# Check if the active tab is the correct

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on selenium to retrieve learning stuff:

During the executing of my code, the target website will defensively open a new tab to stop my process.

I tried to check the `current_url`, but it does not work as expected

```
   if browser.current_url != start_url:
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

How could I check like this:

```
    if browser.current_tab != tab[0]:
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: May be try to use `cached = driver.current_window_handle` to save the start status first, then check by `if cached in browser.window_handles` ?

Comment: @Painter You have to build up a logic to switch to the new tab considering that the  desired tab is not your parent tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.current_window_handle` returns a unique string identifying to your currently opened tab. So you can first store the desired tab somewhere and then compare it to the current tab whenever you want:

```
desired_tab = driver.current_window_handle  #storing the handle in a variable
if driver.current_window_handle != desired_tab:
   driver.switch_to_window(desired_tab)  #switching to the tab in case it's not
```